# How to display php file output inside a html div?

Tags: php, html, css, gallery

Alright, so I'm trying to embed a php script that outputs a gallery of images onto my html div container. However, after an hour or so of searching I'm coming up clueless.

http://craftedbyfrank.com/test/instagram.php

That's the link to the php gallery script.

I want to display it onto the main page inside that div.
[REMOVED] - thanks!

I've tried the following, but I believe it's just wrong. I get no output.

```
 <div id="container">
 <?php include "instagram.php"; ?>
 </div>
```

I'm trying to avoid actually pasting the php script into the html file.

Comment: How are you outputting the `IMG`s? What's the PHP look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php is not being parsed on your server. If you view the html source you see the actual php code you are using to include the file. Make sure that php is installed or you're not embedding the php from a cms that's encoding your tags.

Comment: I'm not seeing this when I inspect the page? I can't see any PHP... but I could be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: inspect the `<div id=container></div>` section.

Comment: Also make sure that the file is named with a `.php` extension.

Comment: oohhhh there was another link added after I started looking :) I now see it.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use AJAX to get the result from the PHP file and write to the containing div.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'http://craftedbyfrank.com/test/instagram.php',
    data:'',
    success: function(data){
            $('#container').html(data);
    }
});
```

You would possible need to adjust to get your fancy box plugin to work.

Comment: thank you, I plan on just making it a php file though. But just out of curiosity, how would you embed the ajax output inside the div?

Comment: In the `success` option, in the `function` it writes the output to the `$('#container')` like above.

Comment: Have a look at the jquery ajax page, it's very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

As @vletech suggested you can use `AJAX` to get the result from the php file.

However the main reason why it does not work is because you are trying to execute the `php` script inside an `.html` file: e.g. your page loads on - [/test/index.html](http://craftedbyfrank.com/test/index.html). In order to work the file has to be with a `.php` extension.